# What are the limits to SSL certificate counts in IIS vs. Azure App Services?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, azure

I apologize that this is probably a little RTFM, but I'm coming up a short on answers. First, I'm reading that while Azure App Services can accommodate 500 domains on any given app, they can only use five SSL certs. Is that correct? Is there a way around that?

Second, I can't find any limit to the number of SSL certs you can bind to a particular app in IIS. Is there a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and there's no workaround. Here're the App Service limits:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits

I'm not sure what's your use case but bear in mind that nothing prevents you from creating several Apps within the same backend which we call Service Plan if cost is your concern. You can even clone one App to create another App with the same source code and configurations, but basically, you'd configure it with distinct domains and each limited to 5 SNI SSL.

Regarding IIS, there's no official word on it, but probably there isn't a limit.

Comment: Basically I'm building a multi-tenant app, where customers will point their domain at the app. The issue is that they all need SSL. Sounds like app services (which I prefer) aren't going to be an option.

Comment: It appears the 5 SNI SSL limit has been removed now (based on the current content at the link in the answer).